# ExtJS proxy/writer with custom header

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I need a header on requests for update actions that contains a tag used by the server for concurrency. What function can I hook/override on the proxy or on the writer to inject this unique header for each operation?

I already have a custom proxy, reader and writer.

The header will look like this: `If-Match:0514e6de-4c76-11df-8ec2-001fd08ec235` where the GUID is being pulled from the record.

Comment: I also need to do basically the same thing on create actions; different header and the value will come from the model config.

Comment: Are you Ext Direct or some home grown server-side stack?

Comment: @MacGyver, I am using RavenDB.

Comment: "beforeRequest" - Fires before a network request is made to retrieve a data object.  I have not tested this, but it's worth taking a look at.  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?178033-How-can-I-set-global-http-headers-for-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best solution that I could come up with is overriding the `doRequest` method in the proxy. I put a switch on the `operation.action` and add and remove headers as needed.

Not pretty, but it works and is reusable.